# How are fixed exposure cameras calibrated on earth for space lighting?

Tags: testing, camera

How are cameras that have a fixed exposure/gain calibrated/tested on earth for space lighting?

I'll further explain with a hypothetical example of what I mean: ISRO launches a Mars-bound planetary science explorer, and a video camera on board is used to verify deployment of a magnetometer as it leaves Earth. The video camera has a fixed exposure and/or gain, so it has to be calibrated on Earth to ensure that the image from the camera will not be over/underexposed (thus occluding the deployment status of the high-gain antenna.)

Since there is a variety of objects in which the camera could be pointing at (Earth, space, or - worst case - the Sun) how are fixed exposure/gain cameras set up/tested to ensure that whatever they want to have in view is clearly visible?

Comment: They may use a test chamber with a well defined and controlled light source. There are sun simulators for spacecraft testing too.

Comment: @Uwe Aren't sun simulators mainly used for thermal testing? Additionally, how could a light source like the sun be approximated given how much brighter it is in space than anything else?

Comment: @jos go on, ask that as a new question.

Comment: @Hobbes I'm not sure what Uwe said was the correct answer, though.

Comment: Uwe wasn't implying a sun simulator is used for camera calibration. He just gave an example of a test chamber with a well-defined light level. Camera calibration would use much lower light levels.

Comment: "how could a light source like the sun be approximated given how much brighter it is in space than anything else" is a good question, and deserves more than a comment. That's why I suggested you ask that as a new question.

Comment: What is the evidence that these video cameras have a fixed exposure and/or gain?

Comment: Spacecraft cameras sometimes have a [fixed aperture](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2019/why-are-there-no-stars.html), perhaps that's what @jos is referring to?

Comment: It looks like the line-scan CCD camera of Mars Observer was actually fixed-exposure, but even there they added the option to adjust offsets during digitization. Given how simple it is to change the exposure time or gain in almost any camera technology, I doubt we're going to find many cameras without this very important feature.

Comment: Integrating Sphere is used to calibrate optics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_sphere